# Implementing involving contains and interval

Tags: java

The method cannot have `if` or `loop`. so it returns `true` if a number is contained in an interval. it works with [1,6]... but how would I fix this so it would work with an open (1,6) or an interval such as [1,6)??'

I want it to be able to return all scenarios with (1,3] (1,3) [1,3) and [1,3], but with no if statements. How could I make one return statement for to be able to return these scenarios

Comment: instead of using >= or <= just use > or < respectively and that should solve your problem (given I understood the question correctly). You can also use switch cases in case you are not allowed to use if statements and loops.

Comment: okay I want it to be able to work wih closed intervals, open , and mixed, but with no if statement.

Comment: Can't you do like `return closed interval || open-closed interval || open interval`?

Comment: could I just do return (n >= leftNum && n <= rightNum || n > leftNum && n < rightNum
        || n >= leftNum && n < rightNum || n > leftNum && n <= rightNum );

Comment: or how would I make it one return statement there

Comment: If you just chained all of those together, wouldn't that be redundant? The fully closed interval is the widest interval you could check, so if you just care about containment in any kind of open/closed interval, that's all you need to check.

Comment: I am stuck then I want to be able to check all of them I also have two boolean methods called isleftendpointin(), which returns leftclosed as true and a boolean method called isrightendpointin(), which return  rightclosed as true

Comment: any help would be much aprreciated

Answer (score 0):

Remove equals sign (=). Like that:

```
return (n > leftNumber && n < rightNumber);
```

You can modify for the others situations (such as [1,6) and (1, 6[)

Answer (score 0):

Change your return statement to look like below if you want to work for interval `[1,6)`

```
return (n >= leftNum && n < rightNum);
```

For `(1,6)`, the return statement can be modified as below

```
return (n > leftNum && n < rightNum);
```

Comment: so how would I have one return statement that would accept all scenarios for closed and open intervals

Comment: I want it to be able to return all scenarios with (1,3] (1,3) [1,3) and [1,3], but with no if statements. How could I make one return statement for that

Answer (score 0):

You'd need a class to define which type of interval you want on each side of the comparison. I would use an enum:

```
public enum Interval {
    CLOSED, OPEN;
}
```

Then you would redefine the method declaration as:

```
public boolean contains(double number, Interval left, Interval right)
```

and redefine the return statement with ternary operators to return the desired boolean.

Comment: my question is how would I just do one return statement I want it to be able to return all scenarios with (1,3] (1,3) [1,3) and [1,3], but with no if statements or loops.

Comment: Ternary statements aren't if statements, and you would only need one return statement. See [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018).

Comment: yeah I was told in specs cant use those either

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this given your restrictions is to add a level of indirection. Your contains method needs to take some sort of interval calculation:

```
boolean contains(double number, Interval interval) {
  double leftNum = this.getLeftEndPoint();
  double rightNum = this.getRightEndPoint();

  return interval.check(leftNum, number, rightNum);
}
```

Then you create the four interval objects you need:

```
class ClosedInterval implements Interval {
  @Override
  boolean check(double lowerBound, double value, double upperBound) {
    return (lowerBound <= value) && (value <= upperBound);
  }
}

class LowerHalfOpenInterval implements Interval {
  @Override
  boolean check(double lowerBound, double value, double upperBound) {
    return (lowerBound < value) && (value <= upperBound);
  }
}

etc...
```

This seems needlessly complex for the problem at hand, though. You could also just define separate methods for each of the various contains variants you want to handle.